# I have 2 dates in Laravel, how can I run a auto generate post to go through between two dates with time period?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to create a Question `(question table)` that has `startDate` and `endDate` and `period` that is in hour (1-2-3-... hours) and `user_id`

Now I want to auto generate question rows in another table (Question_user) between two dates with period

ex:

```
startDate = 2019-11-01 00:00:00

endDate = 2019-11-20 12:00:00

period = 12
```

Now I want to create questions in (Question_user) at:

```
2019-11-01 00:00:00

2019-11-01 12:00:00

2019-11-02 00:00:00

...
```

How can I do this?

```
*Date format -->Year/Month/Day
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller , add below function :

```
protected function GenerateDateRange(Carbon $start_date, Carbon $end_date,$period)
{
$dates = [];
for($date = $start_date; $date->lte($end_date); $date->addHours($period)) {
    $dates[] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
return $dates;
}
```

and use it like this :

```
$dateRanges=$this->GenerateDateRange(Carbon::parse("2019-11-01 00:00:00"),Carbon::parse("2019-11-20 12:00:00"),12);
```

then for loop through $dateRanges and insert your data .